# Printing a random number gives an error in Alexa's Skill

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to do a simple Alexa Skill, following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sj7NqS7yytw) tutorial (which is quite simple, I may add).

The problem is, I am actually having a problem I do not seem to understand. In the second part of the tutorial, the guy shows how to debug, but the status of my error is `succeeded`, so I do not really understand what is going on. Alexa just says: `There has been an error with he skill you requested` and exits.

If the intent detected is `test`(just saying "give me the test results" works):

```
def get_test_response():
    session_attributes = {}
    card_title = "Test"
    number=random.randint(0,100)
    speech_output = "This is the test result",number, "%"
    should_end_session = False
    return build_response(session_attributes, build_speechlet_response(
        card_title, speech_output, reprompt_text, should_end_session))
```

Before printing the random number, it worked fine. In fact, in another function, I am getting a random value of a string, and it works just fine!

(Example code of what works fine with random:)

```
compliments=['you have beautiful eyes', 'you are really kind', 'I like your hair color', 'you smell nice!']
speech_output = compliments[random.randint(0,len(compliments)-1)]
```

I tried executing the code in python console (to check any errors) and it worked fine. The error alexa is displaying in the debug tool is the next one:

(Im hiding the request id's just in case):

```
Response:
null

Request ID:
"REQUESTID IM HIDING IT JUST IN CASE, NOT IMPORTANT"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: REQUESTID IM HIDING IT JUST IN CASE, NOT IMPORTANT Version: $LATEST
Incoming request...
on_session_ended requestId=amzn1.echo-api.request.hiding this one also, sessionId=amzn1.echo-api.session.and hiding this one
END RequestId: hiding this one
REPORT RequestId: hiding this one   Duration: 34.62 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 48 MB
```

My guess is that something about `"this is the test result", number, "%"`is wrong, because the rand is working fine... And I can't seem to find a solution.

**Edit:**

Other solutions that I have tried:

```
number=random.randint(0,100)
st='this is the result of the test '
st+=str(number)
st+='%'
speech_output = st
```

Still not working. Contacted the Alexa Support to see what am I doing wrong.

I also tried with the formatting:

```
speech_output = "This is the test result {}%".format(number)
```

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is. What are you seeing/hearing and how is that different from what you expect? Note though that that `speech_output` line almost certainly doesn't do what you expect; that creates a tuple of three elements. You probably mean `speech_output = "This is the test result {}%".format(number)`.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question! Alexa says `there has been an error with the skill you requested`, and exits. So basically the problem is the string format, right? That was my guess...  I tried changing by saving the hole response in a variable, and printing that variable! Like var="the res.."etc` and `speech_output=var`, but same thing @DanielRoseman

Comment: Yes but as I say, doing what you're doing creates a tuple, whether you save it in a variable first or not. You need to create a string, either as I show using string formatting or simply by concatenating.

Comment: That's just a suggestion but, have you tried to concatenate it as an str object ? like `speech_output = "This is the test result "+ str(number) `

Comment: Okay that sounds good actually. Stupid mistake from me... Thanks @DanielRoseman

Comment: Yeah, the "str" was quite an easy solution actually... Thanks! I'll try it right away @Ayato_k

Comment: Np! Did it worked actually ?

Comment: Nope... Same error. Even doing `"this is the result" +str(1)+"%" ` (just a `1`or whatever), gives the error, so it is definetly how it is formatted @Ayato_k

Comment: Why do you still add a '%' ? the exact line would just be : 
`speech_output = "This is the test result " + str(number)`

Comment: Well, imagine I just want it to show a `%` (like, "the result is 54%"). Anyways, taking it out does not solve it. I am not sure how Alexa's handler works on the back of this... @Ayato_k

Comment: Oh ok, my bad, thought you were trying to format data in the string or something

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
speech_output = "This is the test result {num}%".format(num=number)
```

speech_output should be a string. In your example, it's a tuple.

Comment: That made sense, but it gives the same error. I even tried `"This is the test result "+ str(number)+'%' ` and nothing changes actually... And the debug tool is quite odd, so it does not show what is wrong.